# Python Boto Deleting Routes?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, network-programming, boto, boto3

I've been trying to find a way to delete routes in AWS programatically. I've built a python application for managing AWS resources using boto and boto3. When dealing with the clean up after deletion of VPC Peering, I have blackholed routes left over. I don't want to delete the Route Tables in question, just the blackholed routes.

The AWS CLI has a delete-route function, but I can't find the corresponding function in boto and I'd prefer not to run the AWS CLI directly from my python app if I can avoid it.

In boto3 (and boto) there are methods for creating routes, but I couldn't find any for deleting routes (just deleting the whole route table). I've searched this out numerous times but haven't come close to finding an answer.

Any help?

Comment: Are you trying to delete the route for a particular CIDR?

Comment: Correct ... I delete the VPC peering and then delete associated routes by CIDR destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do see a method in boto 2.38.

```
class boto.vpc.VPCConnection

delete_route(route_table_id, destination_cidr_block, dry_run=False)
```

> Deletes a route from a route table within a VPC.
>
> Parameters:
>
> route_table_id (str) – The ID of the route table with the route.
>
> destination_cidr_block (str) – The CIDR address block used for
> destination match.
>
> dry_run (bool) – Set to True if the operation
> should not actually run.
>
> Return type:    bool Returns:   True if
> successful

Comment: Wow I suck at reading. Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!